# Is it possible to replicate a darkroom light filter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I want to have some `UIViews` and `UILabel`s so that my wife can use my app in her darkroom. I think I need to create something akin to a [Kodak 13A Filter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/27641-REG/Kodak_1796689_13_Amber_Safelight_Filter.html)

So far, I'm using `UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`. I'm not sure this is the best solution, and I'd very much appreciate ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Not getting your question. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: This is interesting. I have no ideas, but love to see what the community comes up with.

Comment: @Ishika. My wife is a film photographer. She uses a darkroom for developing and printing. The only light that's possible when she's printing is what's called a "Safe Light". I have some small apps that she would like to use when she's working (in the dark). So, I'm trying to get my views to replicate the filtering function of actual safe lights. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes sir. I got your point now :)

Comment: Well just as a suggestion, how about keeping your brightness as per requirement while using the app ->  UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.1)

Comment: nice Ishika, I will try that. We're about to run some tests with darkroom paper.